# Renaming a file in NERDTREE

Tags: vim, rename, nerdtree

Is it possible to rename a file in NERDTree? I know about the m menu but there is no rename option.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use `Move`, `(m)ove the current node` in the m menu to rename.

Comment: You should learn to accept and vote on answers that has been helpful to you

Comment: Is there a way to rename it without typing out the full path a 2nd time?

Comment: Note: it does not update the imports of other files.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you pick a node in the tree, then press "m" to reveal the hidden menu. This is crazy!

Answer (score 11):

Just to clarify @iMom0's answer:

To rename a file in NerdTree, navigate to it, then press `mm`.

It will open a prompt with the old full path already written for you, which you can modify to type the new name of the file.

Comment: Still the best answer after 10 years and 3 months.